# Renaming columns in pandas based on strings in list

Tags: python, pandas

Im trying to replace the column names of a dataframe (`sens_second_X`) based on the strings in a list (`updated_fist_stage`) being substrings to the column names. 
`updated_fist_stage = ['ccc_230', 'LN_S_P500', 'mf_100']` 
and

```
sens_second_X.columns = ['resid', 'ccc_230_TY',
       EQ_ETF', 
       'LN_S_P500_changes', 'mf_100_equity', 'inflows_2009',
        'inflows_2010']
```

I try to do this as follows:

```
def renaming_fun(x):
    for var in updated_fist_stage: 
        if var in x:
            return var
        return x
sens_second_X.columns = map(renaming_fun, sens_second_X.columns)
```

but I get that only `ccc_230` has been renamed in the dataframe and the output is as follows:

```
sens_second_X.columns = ['resid', 'ccc_230',
       EQ_ETF', 
       'LN_S_P500_changes', 'mf_100_equity', 'inflows_2009',
        'inflows_2010']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like below with `str.extract`

```
mapped = sens_second_X.columns.str.extract(r'({})'.format('|'.join(updated_fist_stage))
                                                        ,expand=False)
sens_second_X.columns = pd.Index(pd.Series(mapped).fillna(pd.Series(sens_second_X.columns)))
```

---

```
Index(['resid', 'ccc_230', 'EQ_ETF', 'LN_S_P500', 'mf_100', 'inflows_2009',
   'inflows_2010'],
  dtype='object')
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `return x` was just at the wrong indent :

```
def renaming_fun(x):
    for var in updated_fist_stage: 
        if var in x:
            return var
    return x  # <---- HERE IS THE CHANGE
sens_second_X.columns = map(renaming_fun, sens_second_X.columns)
```

What happened to you before : the `if` condition was verified for `ccc_230`, it returned `var`, and then it returned `x` for the rest of the iterator. So the function `renaming_fun()` was only called once